# Why is Rust unable to figure out the correct `from_iterator` to use when constructing a nalgebra::MatrixN?

Tags: rust, nalgebra

I have a struct defined as:

```rust
use nalgebra::{
    allocator::Allocator, DefaultAllocator, Dim, DimName, MatrixN, RowVectorN, VectorN, U1,
}; // 0.22.0

pub struct Filter<Order: Dim + DimName>
where
    DefaultAllocator:
        Allocator<f64, Order, Order> + Allocator<f64, Order> + Allocator<f64, U1, Order>,
{
    a: MatrixN<f64, Order>,
    b: VectorN<f64, Order>,
    c: RowVectorN<f64, Order>,
    d: f64,
    x: VectorN<f64, Order>,
}
```

In my unit test module, I want to construct an instance of `Filter`:

```rust
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use nalgebra::U2;

    fn a_filter() -> Filter<U2> {
        let a: MatrixN<f64, U2> = MatrixN::from_iterator([1., -0., 1., 0.].into_iter());

        Filter {
            a,
            b: VectorN::zeros(),
            c: RowVectorN::zeros(),
            d: 0.,
            x: VectorN::zeros()
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `MatrixN::from_iterator()` results in compile errors. Similar errors occur in the calls to `::zeros()`:

> ```
> error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
>   --> src/lib.rs:22:44
>    |
> 22 |         let a: MatrixN<f64, U2> = MatrixN::from_iterator([1., -0., 1., 0.].into_iter());
>    |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ multiple `from_iterator` found
>    |
>    = note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, C>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #3 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #4 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
>
> error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
>   --> src/lib.rs:26:25
>    |
> 26 |             b: VectorN::zeros(),
>    |                         ^^^^^ multiple `zeros` found
>    |
>    = note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, C>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #3 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #4 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
>
> error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
>   --> src/lib.rs:27:28
>    |
> 27 |             c: RowVectorN::zeros(),
>    |                            ^^^^^ multiple `zeros` found
>    |
>    = note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, C>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #3 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #4 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
>
> error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
>   --> src/lib.rs:29:25
>    |
> 29 |             x: VectorN::zeros(),
>    |                         ^^^^^ multiple `zeros` found
>    |
>    = note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, C>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #3 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C>>::Buffer>`
>    = note: candidate #4 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
> ```

It is not clear to me why Rust is unable to figure out the correct `from_iterator` to use. Is it because I've had to specify `DefaultAllocator` in the definition of `Filter`? If so, what's the cleanest workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; DR;** A [workaround](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c54e81667aafdeab787f7c21c266b4c4) for your code:

```
fn a_filter() -> Filter<U2> {
    let a = MatrixN::<f64, U2>::from_iterator([1.0, -0., 1., 0.].iter().copied());

    Filter {
        a,
        b: VectorN::<f64, U2>::zeros(),
        c: RowVectorN::<f64, U2>::zeros(),
        d: 0.,
        x: VectorN::<f64, U2>::zeros()
    }
}
```

You have to specify the order in the call of `zeros()` instead of guessing it from the return type.

The `from_iterator` has the additional problem that [`array::into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html#impl-IntoIterator) does not return an iterator over the values but over references to the values, just like `iter()` (yes, is is perplexing, and there is a lint for that, IIRC), so you need to add a `copied()` to get the proper iterator type.

---

This is the minimum code that shows your error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=33c9c12bd46d32511662f718fae503fd)):

```
use nalgebra::{
    VectorN, U3
};
fn main() {
    let x: VectorN<f64, U3> = VectorN::zeros();
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
 --> src/main.rs:5:40
  |
5 |     let x: VectorN<f64, U3> = VectorN::zeros();
  |                                        ^^^^^ multiple `zeros` found
  |
  = note: candidate #1 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, C>>::Buffer>`
  = note: candidate #2 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, R, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
  = note: candidate #3 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, C>>::Buffer>`
  = note: candidate #4 is defined in an impl for the type `nalgebra::Matrix<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic, <nalgebra::DefaultAllocator as nalgebra::allocator::Allocator<N, nalgebra::Dynamic, nalgebra::Dynamic>>::Buffer>`
```

If you look careful at the candidates, they are just a the full names of:

```
candidate #1: Matrix<N, R, C, _>
candidate #2: Matrix<N, R, Dynamic, _>`
candidate #3: Matrix<N, Dynamic, C, _>`
candidate #4: Matrix<N, Dynamic, Dynamic, _>`
```

So they have something to do with that `Dynamic` thing... If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.22.0/nalgebra/base/dimension/struct.Dynamic.html) it is not very helpful, but if you look at the example in the [`zeros()`](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.22.0/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#method.zeros) function it has a hint:

```
let v = Vector3::<f32>::zeros();
let dv = DVector::<f32>::zeros(3);
let m = Matrix2x3::<f32>::zeros();
let dm = DMatrix::<f32>::zeros(2, 3);
```

Wait... didn't it take 0 arguments? Well, looking at the code, although the documentation does not say it, it looks like `zeros()` takes as many arguments as they have `Dynamic` in the generic types. And `Vector3<T>` is an alias for `Vector<T, U3>`, `DVector<T>` is an alias for `Vector<T, Dynamic>` and so on.

You may still think that the compiler could deduce the function anyway, because the return type and the argument numbers are different for each version of `zero()`, but that is not how the compiler works: there is no function overload in Rust. If a function name resolves to more than one function it is an error.

Consider this much simpler code that shows a similar error:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    t: T,
}

impl Foo<u8> {
    fn new() -> u8 {
        0
    }
}

impl Foo<u32> {
    fn new() -> u32 {
        0
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t: u8 = Foo::new(); // error!
}
```

Note that it doesn't matter if both functions return the same or different types, or even whether they have the same number of arguments, it is always a compiler error.

The workaround for my code is:

```
fn main() {
    let t: u8 = Foo::<u8>::new();
}
```